# Sculpt brush not orienting to mesh surface correctly

Tags: sculpting, error

For some meshes when I go into sculpt mode the brush does not orient to the surfaces of the mesh correctly, essentially acting perpendicular to the mesh.  This causes my sculpting to occur in tightly packed lines, instead of a nice circle on the surface.  This happens with and without Dyntopo enabled.  Below you can see a screenshot of the brush which should be a circle on the surface is instead perpendicular to it, and the strange vertical sculpting as a result.  My meshes all have correct face orientation as well.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this one when the scale of the object was not applied. Try Ctrl+A in object mode and apply the scale.

Comment: @Blunder looks like that fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

@Blunder fixed the issue for me, I needed to apply the scale of the objects.

Comment: Thanks - applying the scale fixed this for me too.

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't help you.

I had the same issue, but with a new unmodified mesh. Trying to use the grab brush and the selection circle was always flat against the screen causing weird results.

Under Falloff shape was set to projected instead of sphere.